# Xcode 6: Converting Universal app to iPhone only app

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I tried by setting devices to iPhone in project settings, as well as in build settings.
No luck.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Xcode 6.1 fixes it (OSX Yosemite).